# Failed to generate binding redirects for 'localhost'. An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net, redirect, binding, nuget, glimpse

Using ASP.NET **WebForms** in Visual Studio 2010, and adding Glimpse to my **WebSite** (not WebApp):

I'm trying to install NuGet Package -> Glimpse.

The install is pretty straightforward:

> PM> Install-Package Glimpse
>
> Successfully installed 'Glimpse 0.79'.
>
> Successfully added 'Glimpse 0.79' to
> localhost.

But then I get an error in pink
**Failed to generate binding redirects for 'localhost'. An item with the same key has already been added.**

I got an error about a reference to "Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure", which I resolved by finding that DLL and placing it in the bin folder for my Website

Now I'm getting an http 404 error on *http://localhost/websiteName/Glimpse/Config*

I'm assuming the error is because the config file does not really exist there, and the route it tried to insert into IIS didn't work properly, so the page cannot be found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a member of the glimpse team.  Unfortunately, glimpse 0.79 does not support WebForms out of the box.

I expect that all the issues you have listed here will "disappear" once we have more official support.

If your really keen to get up and running, I recommend grabbing the source from gitHub.com/Glimpse and manually referencing Glimpse.Net.

I've also marked this SO question to make sure that we test out your use case when we are preparing to release with official support for WebForms.

Comment: Looks like glimpse is supposed to support WebForms given the info on the website, unfortunately I still get this error. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You should no longer go to glimpse/config, instead go to Glimpse.axd. Also, do you have the most to to date version of NuGet itself? 1.4 as of time of writing.